# Reading string with NSDictionary iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, theos

I was wondering how i can build an app that reads text / strings from settings .
Yes this is only for jailbroken devices . And yes i know i cant put it to the appstore .

I already know how to do it with int or bool but i dont have any idea for string , please help me !
Here is the code :

```
int F1;
bool F2;
```

This is how it reads it :

```
F1 = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.xx.pxx.plist"]valueForKey:@"kF1"]intValue];
F2 = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.xx.pxx.plist"]objectForKey:@"kF2"]boolValue];
```

EDIT1:
And how or what do i have to change in the settings plist :

```
    <dict>
        <key>cell</key>
        <string>PSSwitchCell</string>
        <key>default</key>
        <true/>
        <key>defaults</key>
        <string>com.xx.pxx</string>
        <key>key</key>
        <string>kF1</string>
        <key>label</key>
        <string>Activate the tool</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings:

```
NSString *string = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.xx.pxx.plist"]objectForKey:@"kF2"];
```